# Как выполнить select?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select category
     , sum(number*(1-abs(sign(region-1)))) as reg1
     , sum(number*(1-abs(sign(region-2)))) as reg2
     , sum(number*(1-abs(sign(region-3)))) as reg3
     , sum(number*(1-abs(sign(region-4)))) as reg4 
from groups 
    JOIN orders USING (id_order) 
WHERE datetime_order >= '$date_start' 
  AND datetime_order <= '$date_end' 
group by category;`
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Этим кодом я получаю таблицу как на картинке.
Всего может быть 8 категорий, то есть значение должны быть цифры от 1 до 8. Но в таблице не факт, что они все будут содержаться, особенно в этот промежуток времени.
Как сделать, чтобы в первом столбце были цифры категорий, а в других соответствующие данные. Хочу, чтобы выводились нули, если по ним нем информации в таблице

Comment: Используйте `LEFT JOIN`... а суммы оберните в `COALESCE`.

Comment: Так а если у меня нет всех категорий в таблице группс. Но в теории их должно быть 8. Как тут быть?

Comment: LEFT JOIN вернёт все записи из таблицы groups, вне зависимости от того, есть к ним соотв. записи правой таблицы или нет.

Answer (score 1):

Как правильно подметил **Akina**, используйте [`LEFT JOIN`](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_explicit_join_operations.html), который оставит все значения из таблицы `groups`. При `left join` в правой таблице `orders` при отсутствии пересекающихся значений будет `null`, поэтому, чтобы корректно использовать `sum`, необходимо добавить [`ifnull`, `coalesce` или `nvl`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp) на выбор:

```
select category
     , sum(ifnull(number*(1-abs(sign(region-1))), 0)) as reg1
     , sum(ifnull(number*(1-abs(sign(region-2))), 0)) as reg2
     , sum(ifnull(number*(1-abs(sign(region-3))), 0)) as reg3
     , sum(ifnull(number*(1-abs(sign(region-4))), 0)) as reg4 
from groups 
    LEFT JOIN orders ON groups.id_order = orders.id_order
         AND datetime_order between '$date_start' and '$date_end'
group by category
```

Comment: Так а если у меня нет всех категорий в таблице группс. Но в теории их должно быть 8. Как тут быть? И данный запрос работает точно также, не заметил никаких отличий, какие бы даты не вводил

Comment: *у меня нет всех категорий в таблице группс. Но в теории их должно быть 8. Как тут быть?* Ждать от MySQL телепатический способностей не следует - он не может придумать то, чего у него нет в таблицах. Если таблица groups не полна - значит, дозаполните её.

Comment: Хорошо, просто думал, что есть другой способ, чем плодить записи, которые не будут никогда использоваться, кроме как для выдачи. А что не так с предложенным кодом выше? когда я ввожу даты, то, все равно, отображаются только те категории, по которым есть информация именно в этот период

Comment: @Ivan обновил ответ. Потому что было условие в `WHERE` на таблицу `orders`, что фактически превращает `left join` в `join`.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp1 (id int, reg1 int default 0, reg2 int default 0, reg3 int default 0, reg4 int default 0);
/* Заполнение */
INSERT INTO temp1 (id) VALUES ('1');
INSERT INTO temp1 (id) VALUES ('2');
INSERT INTO temp1 (id) VALUES ('3');
INSERT INTO temp1 (id) VALUES ('4');
INSERT INTO temp1 (id) VALUES ('5');
INSERT INTO temp1 (id) VALUES ('6');
INSERT INTO temp1 (id) VALUES ('7');
INSERT INTO temp1 (id) VALUES ('8');
INSERT INTO temp1 (id) VALUES ('9');

SELECT t.id, coalesce(subquery.reg1, t.reg1), coalesce(subquery.reg2, t.reg2), coalesce(subquery.reg3, t.reg3), coalesce(subquery.reg4, t.reg4)
FROM temp1 t
  LEFT JOIN
  (
    select category, sum(number*(1-abs(sign(region-1)))) as reg1,
                     sum(number*(1-abs(sign(region-2)))) as reg2,
                     sum(number*(1-abs(sign(region-3)))) as reg3,
                     sum(number*(1-abs(sign(region-4)))) as reg4
    from groups JOIN orders USING (id_order)
    WHERE datetime_order >= '$date_start' AND datetime_order <= '$date_end'
    group by category
  ) subquery ON t.id = subquery.category;

DROP TABLE temp1;
```

В итоге все хорошо работает через временную таблицу

Comment: Разве данный мною запрос не отрабатывает? Через создание временной таблицы странный вариант, с хорошим костылем.

Comment: Там что-то некорректно было( И что если в таблице не будет всех вариантов category...

Comment: У вас в таблице изначально должны быть все категории. Иначе странно получается, что вы хотите все категории в выборке, которых изначально нет. Это как лезть в холодильник за соком, который вы не купили, и хотеть, чтобы он там появился)